# Use OgreXML with Blender

Tags: blender

How can I use OgreXML with Blender (how can I install it). Is there a folder that I have to copy it to in the Blender source, or is there an install button in the GUI?

Comment: You mean OgreXML, right?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes